# System.speech em português-Brasil

Tags: c#, .net, reconhecimento-de-voz

Gostaria de saber se por meio do [System.speech](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg145021(v=vs.110).aspx) posso usar no português - brasileiro.

Meu sistema operacional encontra-se no idioma Inglês. Já baixei todos os pacotes necessários, e se eu colocar no idioma inglês(en-US), o meu programa funciona perfeitamente! Consigo fazer perguntas e obter respostas pelo script que desenvolvi. Porém, se eu mudar para português(pt-BR), eu recebo o erro "*Nenhum reconhecedor da identificação necessária encontrado. Nome do parâmetro: culture*"

```
static CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

Atualmente eu defino o idioma por esta linha. Então voltando a pergunta principal: é possível usar o idioma português no System.speech?

Comment: Respondi lá no outro post, pois este está marcado como duplicado.